# Unable to reach dir with script after PHP upgrade

Tags: php

I was asked to fix a site that was fine just days ago and now is not able to include files due to the host's upgrade of the PHP to v.5.3

There's a script that reads directory and builds a list of PDFs in it. FOr some reason the script stopped working and I get the following error messages:

> failed to open dir: No such file or directory...

However I see the directory on the server and if I point to a file directly it opens.

Earliuer I had an issue when I was trying to include files and was getting somewhat similar messages. It seems the problem is caused by a [deprecated php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) setting: register_globals = on. in PHP 5.3

What are the possible solutions?

Comment: Try `var_dump`ing `scandir` to see what PHP sees.

Comment: Can you post the part of the code that reads the dir and builds the list. Also what are the permissions for the directory?

Answer (score 1):

May be this dir was in old php.ini `include_path` directive